# Not prompting for password

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

We are currently looking to move from eclipse to visual studio code.

After opening our project folder, we are automatically setup with our git. Problem is whenever I try to do an action it gives this.

> Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). fatal: Could not
> read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists

We currently do not have SSH setup, and instead in eclipse it prompted us for a password, but this is not happening in visual studio code.

I did some research, went to look for my .ssh folder. The only file that exists is 'known_hosts' so no sshfd_config file, so I downloaded one and set

## PasswordAuthentication yes

As some people have suggested. Still not working.

Can anyone explain how get the prompt?

Comment: Have you tried quitting VS Code, from the prompt using `ssh-add` and re-opening VS Code?

Comment: can you please share result of command 
>> git remote -v
Check if the git remote url (probably origin) is showing an http or ssh